# com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am getting the 'com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated' error always, can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong in my code?

```
Properties mailprops = new Properties();
mailprops.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
mailprops.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "MyHost");
mailprops.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "UserName");
mailprops.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", "Password");

Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailprops, null);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
message.setSubject(mySubject);
message.addRecipient(To);
message.addFrom(from address);

try{
Transport.send(message);
}catch (SendFailedException sfe) {
}catch (MessagingException mex) {
}
```

Comment: Well, `Client was not authenticated` means your username and/or password are incorrect. Have you verified they are correct?  Can you use them to send mail using a mail client such as Thunderbird?  Are you connecting to the right port to submit email?

Comment: My credentials are proper actually. Yes, I am able to send emails actually using any other client.

Answer (score 2):

Try below approach,
Provide the `Authenticator`  object to create the `session` object

```
public class MailWithPasswordAuthentication {
public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
new MailWithPasswordAuthentication().run();
}
private void run() throws MessagingException {
Message message = new MimeMessage(getSession());
message.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("to@example.com"));
message.addFrom(new InternetAddress[] { new InternetAddress("from@example.com") });
message.setSubject("the subject");
message.setContent("the body", "text/plain");
Transport.send(message);
}
private Session getSession() {
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter", authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "mail.example.com");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");
return Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);
}
private class Authenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private PasswordAuthentication authentication;
public Authenticator() {
String username = "auth-user";
String password = "auth-password";
authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
}
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
return authentication;
}
}
}
```

Comment: I missed this property
`properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
        Transport trans = sess.getTransport("smtp");
        try {
            String host = sess.getProperty("mail.smtp.host");
            String port = sess.getProperty("mail.smtp.port");
            String user = sess.getProperty("mail.smtp.user");
            String password = sess.getProperty("mail.smtp.password");
            int prt = port == null ? -1 : Integer.parseInt(port);
            trans.connect(host, prt, user, password);
            trans.sendMessage(message,
                    message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        } finally {
            trans.close();
        }
```

UPDATE:

Or rather:

```
int prt = port == null ? 25 : Integer.parseInt(port);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. enable authentication.
2. enable STARTTLS.
3. create Authenticator object to pass in Session.getInstance argument.

Sample code:

props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

```
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            //override the getPasswordAuthentication method
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
```

Answer (score 0):

You [don't need an Authenticator](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes) as some answers suggest.  There is no `mail.smtp.password` property.  Call the [Transport.send method that takes a username and password](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send-javax.mail.Message-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Yeah, but my Session.getDefaultInstance(mailprops, null) is not setting up the properties that I am passing. It is taking default values always. Why?

Comment: Mistake by me, is it?

Comment: Yes.  Did you read the FAQ?  What part didn't you understand?